# Why is jQuery $("td:eq(0)") slower than $("td").eq(0)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I am using jQuery 1.7.1 and I'm trying to find out why the following code takes 4600 MS, if I change the `:eq(0)` to `:first` it is the same result.

```
$("tr:eq(0) td"); // x10000 takes 4600ms
$("tr").eq(0).find("td"); // x10000 takes 470ms
```

The second codes is almost 10 times as fast! And it's only written differently.

Also if I use a selector like, just selecting an ID or looking within a node:

```
someparent.find("#test") // x10000 takes 500ms
$("#test") // x10000 takes 100ms
$("div#test") // x10000 takes 470ms
```

I would say, if I pass an `div#test` would be faster than `#test` but it is 5 times slower. Why?

I have done all runs a couple of times and it is real slow if I do the same thing different.

**Why is using the selector slower then using functions?**

Comment: Firefox 8.0 I'm currently using, but I expect it takes longer in all browsers.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Answer [right from the horse's mouth](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/):

> Additional Notes:
>
> Because `:eq()` is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using `:eq()`
>   cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM `querySelectorAll()`
>   method. For better performance in modern browsers, use
>   `$("your-pure-css-selector").eq(index)` instead.

I should add that the aforementioned [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll) API is [supported in *all* modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/queryselector), so it can be "indiscriminately" used as a drop-in replacement for `getElementById` etc.

Comment: So the reason why `:first-child` is real fast, is because it is a CSS 3 selector? So I need to use `:first-child` or split up my queries.

Comment: The first part is clear, but why is the lookup for the ID slower if I defined a parent? I thought if I give it a parent, it doesn't have to loop through all nodes.

Comment: @Niels, `:first-child` is not the same as `:eq(0)`.

Comment: @Niels: Because it's a CSS3 selector *that is also supported by the browsers* -- if jQuery were forced to emulate it on some browser the result would be different. As for the id selector w/ parent or not: probably because without a parent, jQuery feeds it directly to `getElementById` or equivalent, while with a parent it also has to walk the DOM to ensure that the element with that id actually has the specified parent.

Comment: Just tried onother piece of code: `$("#test a")` => 700ms, `$("#test").find("a")` => 300ms, can't find out why because both are valid CSS selectors.

Comment: @Niels: Under the hood, different native API methods will be used. The first one will use `querySelectorAll`, and the second one I think uses `getElementById` followed by `getElementsByTagName`, both of which will usually be extremely fast, and generally faster than `querySelectorAll`, which is a more complex method, and doesn't have as many years of tweaking behind it.

Comment: In response to the first comment, it's simply because it is a CSS selector. `querySelectorAll()` accepts *any* selector that the browser supports in a stylesheet, where applicable, regardless of whether or not it's even part of the standard.

Comment: @BoltClock 
If you have a large number of elements matching your selection, it seems weird that `:eq(0)` wouldn't be faster because I would think that the method stops iterating after the first element has been found where .eq(0) would take the result set after everything has been retrieved. I understand that it doesn't work that way, but is it because the jquery selector doesn't store the actual elements.. it stores the query for those elements?

Answer (score 6):

jQuery is built off the [Sizzle library](http://sizzlejs.com/). Sizzle takes advantage of native browser calls wherever possible.

`'tr'` is a valid selector for `querySelectorAll` which operates very quickly. Once the list of `'tr'` elements is acquired, `.eq()` simply does an index lookup which is very fast.

`'tr:eq(0)'` is not a valid selector, so it has to iterate over every element in the DOM.

This discrepancy in benchmarking is noted in the [jQuery docs for `:eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/):

> Because `:eq()` is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using `:eq()` cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM `querySelectorAll()` method. For better performance in modern browsers, use `$("your-pure-css-selector").eq(index)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery does not need to split the input string into functions and convert this sequence of string functions into appropriate method calls.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly why, but I hade a similar problem in another language and it depends on the function itself:

`$("tr:eq(0) td");` needs to be parsed to work, and then do the function call.

`$("tr").eq(0).find("td");` only does the function call